# Show PrimeFaces Error Message on login fail

Tags: jakarta-ee, primefaces

I want to show a PrimeFaces error message if a login fails. This is what I have so far:

Model:

```
public String login() {
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("SelectUserByLogin");
    query.setParameter("alias", alias);
    query.setParameter("password", password);

    // TODO: type safety
    List<User> result = query.getResultList();

    if (result.size() == 1) {
        userLoggedIn = result.get(0);
        return "home?faces-redirect=true";
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

View:

```
        <h:panelGrid>
            <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.alias}" for="alias" />
            <p:inputText id="alias" required="true"
                value="#{mbUserHandler.alias}" />
            <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.password}" for="password" />
            <p:password id="password" required="true"
                value="#{mbUserHandler.password}" />
            <h:panelGroup />
            <p:commandButton action="#{mbUserHandler.login()}"
                value="#{msg.login}" />
        </h:panelGrid>
```

login() returns null if the user is not found and can't be logged in. So this means, nothing happens in the view. In this case I would like to show a PrimeFaces error message.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/message/messages.xhtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From here: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/message/messages.xhtml

```
public String login() {
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("SelectUserByLogin");
    query.setParameter("alias", alias);
    query.setParameter("password", password);

    // TODO: type safety
    List<User> result = query.getResultList();

    if (result.size() == 1) {
        userLoggedIn = result.get(0);
        return "home?faces-redirect=true";
    } else {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "error logging in", "Error logging in"));
        return null;
    }
}



       <h:panelGrid>
            <p:messages showDetail="true"/>
            <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.alias}" for="alias" />
            <p:inputText id="alias" required="true"
                value="#{mbUserHandler.alias}" />
            <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.password}" for="password" />
            <p:password id="password" required="true"
                value="#{mbUserHandler.password}" />
            <h:panelGroup />
            <p:commandButton action="#{mbUserHandler.login()}"
                value="#{msg.login}" />
        </h:panelGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a messages Box somewhere on the page where you want to you message.
For Example (Autoupdate makes it update itself on ajax requests which do not update the page. This is important because primefaces standard behaviour is to use ajax for commandButton-Actions):

```
<p:messages autoUpdate="true" id="messagebox" />
```

You can then add messages to this messagebox from your bean:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "My Message", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

...

```
<p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" /> 
<p:commandButton action="#{mbUserHandler.login()}"
            value="#{msg.login}"  update="growl" />
```

...

```
else {
    return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Second Message", "Additional Message Detail"));
}
}
```

I think you must check http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ page.